# Why my app crash when i try to take a preview from camera with SurfaceView?

Tags: android

Why my app crash when i try to take a preview from camera with SurfaceView on android?
When I build Android Studio hasn't errors.

This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private Camera camera; 
    static private SurfaceView surfaceView; 
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camera_surface);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder(); 
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        camera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        try
        {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Somebody can help me? I will wait your answer.

Comment: Post your layout.xml

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_surface"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                </SurfaceView>    
</RelativeLayout>
This is my layout.xml @Willis

Comment: @arthursfreire this is my layout:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_surface"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                </SurfaceView>    
</RelativeLayout>